# JavaMail with Spring - Missing Imports

Tags: java, spring

I am getting a

> The import cannot be resolved

error for the following imports,

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
```

I have the following libraries in the classpath, but I not sure which jar file has the above-mentioned imports. Does anybody have any idea?

```
     org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Add `org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: I downvoted your question because I didn't see any honest research on your part. You could have googled your import to find out which jar file might contain your import.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are missing `org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar`

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

if you're using Maven.

Comment: @Sachin Make sure to accept an answer if you found it useful.

Comment: @pacman : if answer is useful, upvote. And if answer solves your problem accept.

Comment: Somebody's concern is Accept and Upvote. I think main concern is Knowledge sharing, help and learning

Answer (score 3):

You should add to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

$mvn clean install
worked for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Spring email boot starter dependency for mail, see below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This will contain both `spring-context-support` & `javax.mail` dependencies

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.context.support-3.x.y.RELEASE.jar is missing. You can download "spring-context-support-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar" from the following URL:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-context-support

Go to Java Build Path and add as external jar.